# Why can't I see all of the files that are in my workspace in xcode in the left sidebar?

Tags: ios, xcode, workspace

I was doing some work on my iOS app and all of a sudden, something really strange began to happen:

For a second or so after I open my workspace, all of the files that I've added to the workspace are visible in the left sidebar as they should be. But after this second passes, a large chunk of these files vanish from the left sidebar. And it's not like they're completely gone - I can see the entire directory structure and files through the dropdown view, as shown in the attached screenshot. But as can  also be seen in the attached screenshot, I cannot see this same information in the left sidebar.

And it's not because I haven't actually added these files to the workspace. I have - when I try to add the files again, all of the files are greyed out...meaning they've already been placed in the project.

I've tried restarting Xcode and restarting my Mac. I'm thinking about deleting the .workspace file and re-running pod install, but I don't want to do that until I've ruled out other options...that I might not be aware of but someone here might be able to quickly point out.

I've tried searching for this particular problem on Stackoverflow and on Google but to no avail.

Help would be much appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look at the bottom of the left sidebar. You have selected the second icon (in blue) which means, you are displaying only the recent files of your project. Unselect it to display all your files.
[image]

Comment: Be also careful when you use the search field on the right of that button. If you type in there and forget it might get confusing at first :D

Comment: I was not able to drag new files also while it was in this mode..great little trick

Comment: That is really confusing if you don't know you accidentally click on that button.